# Activerecord Group by ENUM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using rails 4.1 and the new enum functionality to include an array of enums in my model class e.g:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base    
  enum status: [:pending, :active, :paused, :complete]

end
```

I want to query campaigns and list a count by status e.g:

```
Campaign.all.group("status").count
```

This simple query works fine however returns the integer value of the enum from the DB.  Is there an easy rails way to convert this to the string representation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just map numbers to related string values:

```
Campaign.all.group(:status).count.map { |k, v| [Campaign.statuses.key(k), v] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 2):

**if you want status wise count**

```
campaigns = Campaign.all.group(:status).count

@campaigns = Campaign.statuses.map { |k, v| [k , campaigns[v] || 0] }
```

**it will give output like**

{"pending"=>0, "active"=>1, "paused"=>0, "complete"=>0}

Comment: this is insane, i've more than 500.000 records.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use rails `#transform_keys` method:

```
Campaign.all.group(:status).count.transform_keys { |k| Campaign.statuses.key(k) }
```